# What support is there for PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) in common languages?

Tags: pcre

I am interested in the power of PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) and wonder whether they are likely to become a de facto approach in all major languages (I am interested in Java). I am prepared to use a library if necessary.

I also could not find a good page in SO describing the pros and cons of PCRE so if this does not exist it could be useful to include this in answers

**EDIT** I am interested in power beyond Java 1.6 regex, particularly named capture groups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that more mainstream languages actually use their own implementation of "Perl-like" regexes than actually use libpcre. Languages that fall into this class include (at the very least) Java, JavaScript, and Python.

Java's `java.util.regex` library uses a syntax that's very heavily based on Perl (approx. version 5.8) regexes, including the rules for escaping, the `\p` and `\P` Unicode classes, non-greedy and "possessive" quantifiers, backreferences, `\Q`..`\E` quoting, and several of the `(?...)` constructs including non-capturing groups, zero-width lookahead/behind, and non-backtracking groups. In fact Java regexes seem to have more in common with Perl regexes than libpcre does. :)

The JavaScript language also uses regexes that are derived from Perl; Unicode classes, lookbehind, possessive quantifiers, and non-backtracking groups are absent, but the rest of what I mentioned for Java is present as well in JS.

Python's regex syntax is also based on Perl 5's, with non-greedy quantifiers, most of the `(?...)` constructs including non-capturing groups, look-ahead/behind and conditional patterns, as well as named capture groups (but with a different syntax than either Perl or PCRE). Non-backtracking groups and 'possessive' quantifiers are (as far as I can see) absent, as are `\p` and `\P` Unicode character classes, although the standard `\d`, `\s`, and `\w` classes are Unicode-aware if requested.

Comment: Thank you. I have clarified my question to show that I am interested in features that Java 1.6 does not support

Comment: Perl, Python, .NET, libpcre. Those are the only implementations I know of that support named capture groups.

Comment: Actually many of the Python extensions will work on modern Perl's.

Answer (score 1):

> I ... wonder whether they [PCRE] are likely to become a de facto approach in all major languages (I am interested in Java).

This calls for speculation, but I think that the answer is "No" ... in the case of Java.  I base this on the fact that I couldn't find *any* worthwhile PCRE implementation for Java.

If there was a *real* need / demand for PCRE in Java, I'd have expected there to be more libraries out there.

---

**UPDATE**

Since I wrote the original answer, more people / groups have implemented Java libraries that provide (or claim to provide) PCRE compatible regexes.

And obviously The Java team may (and has) add some Perl features to Java's regex support over time.  For example, named capture groups were added in Java 7.

But full PCRE compatibility doesn't seem to be a high priority goal for the Java team.  For example:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027651
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8258119

And given that full compatibility would likely break a subset of existing Java applications, I still think that the answer is No.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but to update it, Java 7 added named capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a split off of this match:

```
(?:
  (?:'[\S\s]*?(?<!\\)') # Consume characters inside of a quoted string
  |(?:\/\*[\S\s]*?\*\/) # Consume multi-line comments
  |(?m:\/{2}[^\n]*$\n)  # Consume single-line comments
)(*SKIP)(*F)            # Fail match if any of the previous matches were found
|(?<=;)                 # Capture position right after semicolon
```

Be sure to use the 'x' and 'g' (if necessary) modifier(s).

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/sK4vX1/3)

Comment: You can add the /x flag inside the re by starting it with `(?x:`

Answer (score -3):

This sounds a lot like a "Is X the One True Way!?" kind of question. PCRE has many shortcomings, the most obvious of which being it's complexity and questionable usefulness. Rarely does there exist a One True Way for anything, and in the realm of regexp libraries, PCRE most certainly is not it.

Perl regular expressions are utter junk in my opinion. Once you get much beyond the feature-set offered by POSIX extended regexps (ERE), you may as well use something like a PEG implementation. The only reason PCRE is used so widely used is because it's easy for people to solve a problem by just dropping in a library.