# Is there any Java API for PCRE regex maching

Tags: java, pcre

we have a requirement to match the PCRE expression against a file name. Tried to find the API regarding it, but unable to find any. Need some suggestion how to achieve it. If any of you have already done, a sample would be more greateful

Comment: possible duplicate of [What support is there for PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) in common languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448164/what-support-is-there-for-pcre-perl-compatible-regular-expressions-in-common-l)

Comment: The "Comparison to Perl 5" section of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html lists the differences. You should check to see if there are any relevant ones. More likely than not it will handle your PCRE just fine. (Pedantic: A "PCRE expression" is like an "ATM machine".)

Comment: Well it does not match recursive pattern, but there are libraries like [java.pcre](https://github.com/raimonbosch/java.pcre) or [JRegex](https://jregex.sourceforge.net/index.html) which are PCRE compliant.