# What's the fastest PCRE to remove everything after a char?

Tags: regex, pcre

Say I have `abcdeXqwerXiop` (edit: we know there are Xs) I would like to get back`abcdeXqwer` -- cut the string at the last occurence of `X` (not including that last char). what's the fastest way to do that? My best idea is

```
preg_replace('/.[^X]+$/', '', $string);
```

Comment: If there's no `X` in the string (and there's at least two characters), your program replaces the whole string by nothing (I think that's not what you want in that case).  In addition, using the dot instead of `X` is too generic and that will slow down the expression. I think that `/X[^X]+$/` is the expression you really want as first argument. It should be faster too, by a factor equal to the length of the string, I guess.

Comment: I edited to say it contains Xs. Also, I would've thought that I will start matching / backtracking from the end of the string because of the anchor? Is there a way to see the execution of the PCRE?

Comment: See chapters 4 and 6 of Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions": http://regex.info/toc3.html. You'll see that there are several kind of engines, let alone implementations. Whether you can visualize or not depends on the actual tool you're using, which you don't cite.

Comment: Actually, the title and tag both says PCRE which is a pretty specific implementation as far as I am aware. http://www.pcre.org/

Comment: I wasn't aware of that library. I was thinking about of the general concept of Perl Compatible Regular Expression, as mentioned in the following post (which also mentions the library): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448164/what-support-is-there-for-pcre-perl-compatible-regular-expressions-in-common-l?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: I do not know as much of micro-optimization as I thought I did -- but noone likes to provide proof.

There is no proof offered whether two function calls are faster than one. So, here's a script:

```
$string = str_repeat('abcdeXqwerXiopreyX', 50) . 'aaaaaaa';
function test($string) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) preg_replace('/X[^X]+$/', '', $string);
}
function test1($string) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, 'X') + 1);
}
test($string);
test1($string);
```

And then I ran `php -d xdebug.auto_trace=1 test.php` to find that the script enters `test()` at 0.0004, enters `test1()` 0.3430 finishes at 0.683. So `test()` takes .3426 while `test1()` takes 0.2652.

We can concur that indeed the two calls are faster.

But, if we want to stick to regular expressions, it is offered that `X[^X]+$' is faster but no proof. I have found a way to debug them. PHP can't but Perl can.

So,

```
$string = 'abcdeXqwerXiop';
$string =~ s/X[^X]+$//;
print $string;
```

And then run `perl -Mre=debug test.pl`. It is much too long to paste here, but the output of this script is 27 lines long, while `.[^X]+$` indeed takes 75 lines, several times as much to find a match.

Edit: this *might* be incorrect because PCRE and Perl are different implementations with likely different optimizations, but I have traced this with xdebug as well and that result concurs.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way would be to skip regex altogether:

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "X") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why regular expressions? This is going to be much faster.

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, 'X'));
```