# What does regex "(?:^(?:dont)$)" mean?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regular expression

```
"(?:^(?:dont)$)"
```

what does this means? what kind of text pattern it can watch with?

Comment: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4zQ5/1)

Comment: @Digigizmo Thanks! Good to know Regx 101. It helps to learn and use regex greatly!

Comment: @Digigizmo it was really painful by reading regex itself. btw, for regex 101, it doesnot support for java but python. Is the regex for the java and python following the same rule and pattern?

Comment: It depends what package/engine you are using but most languages will implement something *"perl-like"* ***i.e.*** the *PCRE* option on regex-101 will cover most general cases while you are learning.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448213/1238344) gives more detail - It's an old post and I'm not completely versed with the different nuances between languages but I'd imagine it's still relevant.

Comment: @Digigizmo Just used it for testing a few cases. It's indeed quite similar in both environments. Many thanks. I actually want to vote your comment as the answer!

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough content to flesh out a decent post - the answer already posted looks to have come from regex-101 and the rest is just general info that can be found by searching - there's no point duplicating content.  You are allowed to answer your own question though if you're not satisfied with the other response you've gotten. If you think there's a broader question that might be useful to others you could contribute by making your initial post more generic and affording a more complete Q&A.  (otherwise feel free to accept the other answer and close the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/"(?:^(?:dont)$)"/
" matches the characters " literally
(?:^(?:dont)$) Non-capturing group
^ assert position at start of the string
(?:dont) Non-capturing group
dont matches the characters dont literally (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
" matches the characters " literally
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, you can consult a regex visualizer like [Regexper](http://regexper.com/#%22(%3F%3A%5E(%3F%3Adont)%24)%22).

[image: svg]