# getting substring regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this kind of line:
`<a href="/verona/4mktg-for-marketing.8526695" title="4MKTG FOR MARKETING SRL">4MKTG FOR MARKETING <strong>SRL</strong> </a>`

I need the field's title. I splitted the string by 'title="' then checked if it matches with this regex: `"[0-9A-Z /.]{3,}"` . But it doesnt work...

The field contains only digits, capital letters, spaces and dots

Thank you

Davide

Comment: do you have to use a regex?  If not, can just find where "title=\"" starts and take substring from where title" ends to next double quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a regular expression, you should use JSoup when dealing with HTML.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element links = doc.select("a");
for (Element l : links) {
    // grab the title attribute value
    System.out.println(l.attr("title"));
}
```

Comment: agreed, anytime when parsing a known format (html, xml, json) don't use RegEx

Answer (score 2):

```
title="([\dA-Z\. ]+)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aNjYsPaPIqhoBEXc)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it with regex (and using `java.util.regex`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448164/what-support-is-there-for-pcre-perl-compatible-regular-expressions-in-common-l) considering PERL-like regexes in Java):

```
str = '<a href="/verona/4mktg-for-marketing.8526695" title="4MKTG FOR MARKETING SRL">4MKTG FOR MARKETING <strong>SRL</strong> </a>';
str = str.replaceAll('.* title="([\s\.A-Z0-9]+)".*', "$1");
```